# Utilizar variavel de uma classe em outra

Tags: javascript, promises

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
    this.retorno.then(function(result){
        let a = result[0].infos.inProgress; 
        var cards = [];
        a.forEach(b => { 
            let card = new Card(b.name, b.type, b.date, b.id);
            cards.push(card);
        });

        let divOpen = document.querySelector("#open");
        let cardView = new CardView(divOpen);
        cardView.load(cards);

    });
```

Ele em si está funcionando perfeitamente, porém gostaria de utilizar a variável cards que contém uma array de objetos em outro método da mesma classe. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não é só persistí-la pelo `this` assim como fez com `this.resultado`?

Comment: Livia, nao tem necessidade de botar que é pergunta iniciante, isso é irrelevante pra duvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

vc pode criar um atributo chamado cards como no exemplo abaixo

```
//um novo atributo na sua classe
cards = [];

this.retorno.then(function(result){
    let a = result[0].infos.inProgress; 
    var cards = [];
    a.forEach(b => { 
        let card = new Card(b.name, b.type, b.date, b.id);
        cards.push(card);
    });

    //fiz dessa forma, por que não se pode usar 'this' dentro de arrow functions
    //, por conta do escopo.
    this.cards = cards;

    let divOpen = document.querySelector("#open");
    let cardView = new CardView(divOpen);
    cardView.load(cards);

 });
}
```

fazendo dessa forma, vc pode usar o **this.cards** em outro método.

sobre escopo de arrow functions, dá uma olhada nesse post, muito bom por sinal:
https://blog.da2k.com.br/2019/01/07/javascript-tudo-sobre-arrow-functions/

espero ter ajudado de alguma forma

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, era tão simples! Obrigada